# How to move from second fragment to first fragment after click on button?

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I created a view pager in that two fragments are used to  move from one fragment to second fragment. In second fragment page I want the following: 
when I click on button, fragments are changed from second to first one fragment; in view pager means second page to first page. First and second fragment have own XML file, and view pager is in main fragment's XML file.

Means:

1. `class ViewPagerMainActivity extends FragmentActivity` contains main xml file that contain ViewPager
2. First and Second fragment class extends fragment and have own design xml file

Now I need to move from second to first fragment. How can I do this?

My `ViewPagerMainActivity` is the following

```
 public class CopyOfViewPagerMainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
    OnClickListener, OnPageChangeListener {

Button btnBack, btnNextImage;
LinearLayout llMainPager;
TelephonyManager telemamanger;
TextView txtOpname, txtCharge;
String operatorCodeName;
int level = -1;
double scale;
int rawlevel;
LinearLayout llayoutMainpager;
int image;
ViewPager pager;
Boolean flagzoom, flagscale, flagfade, flagdepth, flagnone, flagpivot,
        flag3d;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.view_pager_main);


    // my  other code here

}

private class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public MyPagerAdapter(
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
        super(fragmentManager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int pos) {
        switch (pos) {

        case 0:
            return FirstFragment.newInstance("");

        case 1:
            return SecondFragment.newInstance("");

        default:
            return SecondFragment.newInstance("Default");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 2; // return no of fragment created by us
    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

}

@Override
public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
```

My first fragment following

```
public class CopyOfFirstFragment extends Fragment implements OnTouchListener ,OnPageChangeListener{

String permanentval = "";
LinearLayout llayoutslide;
LinearLayout llayoutpassword;
int image;
TextView txtTime, txtDay, txtmissedCall, txtChargePercent,txtSMS;
ImageView imgCharge;
int charge;
Boolean flagAnimzoom;
ViewPager pchange;


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater
            .inflate(R.layout.sliding_lock_pager, container, false);

    // my all code here
            return v;
}

public static CopyOfFirstFragment newInstance(String text) {

    CopyOfFirstFragment f = new CopyOfFirstFragment();
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putString("msg", text);
    f.setArguments(b);

    return f;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}


}
```

My second fragment

```
public class CopyOfSecondFragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {

    LinearLayout llayoutPasswordEnter,llayoutPasswordConfirm,llayoutPasswordPager;
    Button btnNext, btnOne, btnTwo, btnThree, btnFour, btnFive, btnSix,
            btnSeven, btnEight, btnNine, btnZero;
    TextView txtClear, txtDone;
    String store = "";
    int one = 0, two = 0;
    String permanentval = "";
    RelativeLayout rlayoutPasswordEnter;
    int image;
    private Vibrator vibrator;
    Boolean getflagvibrate=false, getflagSounds=false;
    MediaPlayer mp;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.password, container,
                false);

        // all code here
        txtDone.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                // in this button i want to move from this fragment to first means i want to display   firt xml file instead of this second one   <----- here want to move 
            }
        });

        return v;
    }
    public void setButtonSize(Button btn) {
        int width = Constant.getDeviceWidth(getActivity()) / 5;
        LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(width, width);
        params.leftMargin = 8;
        params.rightMargin = 8;
        btn.setLayoutParams(params);
    }

    public static CopyOfSecondFragment newInstance(String text) {

        CopyOfSecondFragment f = new CopyOfSecondFragment();
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putString("msg", text);
        f.setArguments(b);
        return f;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also do through this, put this code in your click method

```
       ((ViewPagerMainActivity)getActivity()).pager.setCurrentItem(0);
```

in setCurrentItem(0)  `0` is whatever activity number you want to go

Answer (score 2):

i find my solutions :use following in my click

```
      final FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction(); 
      ft.replace(R.id.details, new NewFragmentToReplace, "NewFragmentTag"); 
      ft.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a not sure to understand what you are trying to do, but if you are trying to change the page programmatically:
`ViewPager.setCurrentItem(int item)` will do the trick.

Comment: viewpager is in main xml file then how to used ViewPager.setCurrentItem(int item) in second frgment

Comment: i just move to second page to first on base of click for example in activity we do this.finish() to end one activity and display back at that type i want to finish second fragment and display first page

Answer (score 0):

you can use `viewPager.setCurrentItem(CURRENT_FRAGMENT_TO_BE_SET)` to do that

Answer (score 0):

make your viewpager at your CopyOfViewPagerMainActivity class Static, and then, call it from another class.

for example,

```
CopyOfViewPagerMainActivity.pager.setCurrentItem(1);
```